# jQuery multiple selector with $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, this, getelementbyid, multiple-instances

is there any way to make this work:

```
$(this, '#foo')
```

with that I want to select "this" element and #bar as well.
For selecting let's say two IDs, it is just as easy as `'#foo, #bar'`, but when I want one of those two to be "this" I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Problem with your approach

```
$(this, '#foo')
```

The above line will search for `this` inside an element with `id` set to `foo`, which isn't what you want here.

---

#### Solution

You can use `add()` for this :

```
var $el = $(this).add('#foo')
```

Now `$el` will contain `$(this)` & `$("#foo")` on which you can perform operations on.

---

#### More info on the methods used

**`add("selector")`**

- Docs : http://api.jquery.com/add/
- What it does : Add elements to the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thank you. I knew my sample code was not working and I thought it was selecting rather <code>#foo</code> inside <code>this</code>. So this is a little surprise, that it work vice versa.And I put it here that way, because it felt to me the closest to the multiple IDs selection.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the approach you're using:

```
$(this, '#foo')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jNcdX/).

Is that this is a context-aware selection, searching for `this` within the `#foo` element (and is identical to `$('#foo').find(this)`), which is valid within jQuery, though I'd imagine somewhat pointless (given that you already have a reference to `this` (I assume, though if not `this` *might* be the `window`)).

In all honesty I'm not entirely sure why the selector 'works' at all, unless given the `this` node jQuery simply discards the context, given that it already 'knows' where the `this` node is and has a reference.

To add to a selection:

```
$(this).add('#foo');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jNcdX/1/).

Or (conversely):

```
$('#foo').add(this);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jNcdX/2/).

References:

- [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [jQuery selector-context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

Answer (score 1):

What you may also be looking for is

```
$('#foo', this)
```

It will find the `foo` id object inside of `$(this)`